# Can I get a 20/40 requirement waiver after cataract lens replacement?

Tags: pilots, medical

I have had lens replacement surgery and now one eye is focused at 16” (close, reading distance)and the other eye is focused at a distance. I have 20/20 vision both at 16” and at distance as long as both eyes are open.

I have a third class private Pilots license and my medical is due. Can I get a waiver because I don’t meet the 20/40 requirement with either eye closed?

For example when my left eye is closed I can not meet the 20/40 requirement with my right eye when it comes to the 16” test and the same goes for my other eye when it comes to the distance test.

Comment: Do you need the third class, or can you get BasicMed?

Answer (score 5):

If you are a member of or join AOPA I recommend consulting AOPA member services for help with questions like this. I have consulted them multiple times and they always get a good answer for me or set me in the right direction.

Of course you can consult an Aviation Medical Examiner (AME) first but I recommend you figure out what you need to do and go into your AME knowing you’ll pass the medical exam... once you’ve failed it can be a nightmare to get your medical back and take a long time (and cost lots of money).

Source: I’m a pilot who has used this service of AOPA before